# Spring Boot v3.0.2: Spring GraphGL Serialization/Deseralization Ignoring Enum String Value and @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, jackson, spring-graphql

I'm having an issue with Spring GraphQL not serializing/deseralizing the value of a Java enum, even when using Jackson's `@JsonProperty`. Example below.

GraphQL Schema Definition

```
type Media { 
    name: String
    type: MediaType
}

enum MediaType {
    IMAGE
    VIDEO
}
```

Java Enum

```
public enum MediaType {

    @JsonProperty("img")
    IMAGE("img"),
    @JsonProperty("video")
    VIDEO("video");

    private final String value;

    MediaType(String type) {
        this.value = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The result from the GraphQL Query:

```
{
    "name: "My Media",
    "type: "IMAGE" // I would like this to be "img"
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

[As stated in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#execution.graphqlsource.runtimewiring-configurer), Spring for GraphQL does not use Jackson for

> GraphQL Java, server applications use Jackson only for serialization
> to and from maps of data. Client input is parsed into a map. Server
> output is assembled into a map based on the field selection set. This
> means you can’t rely on Jackson serialization/deserialization
> annotations. Instead, you can use custom scalar types.

In your case, there are several things to consider.

First, your schema declares an enum `MediaType` with possible values `IMAGE, VIDEO`. This means that [only those values are allowed in the actual GraphQL response](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Enums). By default, [GraphQL Java will try and map enum values to Java enums](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/data-mapping#enums).

Returning an unexpected value (from a schema point of view) should result in an error like this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Can't serialize value (/findMedia) : Invalid input for Enum 'MediaType'. Unknown value 'VIDEO'",
      "path": [
        "findMedia"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "DataFetchingException"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "findMedia": null
  }
}
```

Now, let's consider that we've fixed the schema with the enum values that you would expect:

```
type Query {
    findMedia: MediaType
}

enum MediaType {
    img
    video
}
```

We can now update the `MediaType` class and remove the Jackson annotations.

```java
public enum MediaType {

    IMAGE("img"),
    VIDEO("video");

    private final String value;

    MediaType(String type) {
        this.value = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    static MediaType fromCustomValue(String value) {
        for (MediaType candidate : values()) {
            if (candidate.value.equals(value)) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown media type '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

You can then teach GraphQL Java how the `MediaType` enum from your schema should map to your Java enum (most of the code can be turned into lambdas, but I've left entire classes for clarity):

```java
@Bean
public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
    return new RuntimeWiringConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configure(RuntimeWiring.Builder wiringBuilder) {
            wiringBuilder.type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("MediaType", typeBuilder -> {
                return typeBuilder.enumValues(new EnumValuesProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public Object getValue(String name) {
                        return MediaType.fromCustomValue(name);
                    }
                });
            })).build();
        }
    };
}
```